# Error while trying to edit a view of a list - Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am receiving the error below when editing the current view of a list in the list webpart:

**The file is not checked out.  You must first check out this document before making changes.**

I am not sure **what's the file** I need to Check Out, as I am modifying the view of a list.

**Note:** I read in a blog that I had to make sure that the versioning settings of the list were turned off (checked to NO) under

Lists Settings --> General Settings.

I review that and they were / are turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Is this custom view or a page where in you have added custom list view webpart.

from your question i think it is later, it might be asking you to check out page so that you can make changes to your list view webpart....